# Breaking a big file down into smaller files on special char in bash script

Tags: bash, parsing, shell

I have a huge file with 800,000 words in it which are separated with | character. I would like to write a bash script that reads the file, on every 1000 | it dump the content into a file and then continues until we have

Comment: Make a request on http://elance.com or re read FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post appears to be cut off, but from what I gather this script should help you get started.

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    FS="|"
    y=1
    outputFile="/tmp/outfile"
}{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        tmpoutput=tmpoutput" "$i
        if (y == 1000) {
            y=1
            print tmpoutput > outputFile
            tmpoutput=""
        } else {
            y++
        }
    }
}END{
    print tmpoutput > outputFile
}' inputFile
```